# How do I enable Get-MailboxFolder to work against other mailboxes?

Tags: permissions, powershell, exchange-2010

Get-MailboxFolder by default seems to only work on one mailbox, that of the logged in user.

I'm trying to leverage the Identity parameter of the cmdlet to connect to other mailboxes.  I discovered that the management role permission is set to "self" which is a relatively safe assignment for all users.

How do I create a different permission for this that only allows Administrators (or a given user) to run GetMailboxFolder for anyone?   I'm concerned about accidentally creating a security hole and enabling other users to gain access to mailboxes that aren't their own.

Answer (score 3):

While [`Get-MailboxFolder`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351164(v=exchg.160).aspx) has this built-in limitation, [`Get-MailboxFolderStatistics`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996762(v=exchg.160).aspx) is designed...

> to retrieve information about the folders in a specified mailbox,
>   including the number and size of items in the folder, the folder name
>   and ID, and other information.

Then there is another administrative [`Get-Mailbox`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123685%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx)  cmdlet:

> Use the `Get-Mailbox` cmdlet to view mailbox objects and attributes,
>   populate property pages, or supply mailbox information to other tasks.

These two can be used together to get information for whole organization at once, e.g.

```
Get-Mailbox | Select-Object alias                                            `
| foreach-object {                                                           `
    Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $_.alias                           `
    | select-object Identity, ItemsInFolder, FolderSize, FolderAndSubfolderSize }
```

This already gives more information than [`Get-MailboxFolder`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351164(v=exchg.160).aspx) would ever have given. Of course you can remove the `ItemsInFolder`, `FolderSize` and `FolderAndSubfolderSize` if they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not allow the [`Get-MailboxFolder` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351164%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to run against another person's mailbox - only the person who owns the mailbox can use the cmdlet to retrieve the folders.

> Use the `Get-MailboxFolder` cmdlet to view folders in your own mailbox.
>   Administrators can't use this cmdlet to view folders in other
>   mailboxes (the cmdlet is available only from the [MyBaseOptions user
>   role](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876910(v=exchg.150).aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

to get the different user' folders you can use the folderpath option

something like that:

Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $username|select folderpath